# Typedef of 2d array of pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, typedef

I am trying to define a type for my 2d array of pointers so I can reduce the mess in my code. I had triple pointers so I thought it looked bad.
I managed to refactor the code using typedef, but it was more like trial and error. I would like to know what this actually means:

```
typedef SomeClass* (&grid8x8)[8][8];
```

And why this functions returns ok values:

```
grid8x8 SomeOtherClass::getGrid()
{
    return grid;
}
```

The syntax of the typedef in this case is what is confusing me.

Comment: Read about [the clockwise/spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) and try again.

Comment: Oh, and I strongly suggest you drop the `&` from the type-alias definition. That will cause problems when and where you can't use references.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg grid8x8 is a reference to 8x8 array of pointers of type SomeClass?

Comment: Good one @JoachimPileborg! Thanks for the rule!

Comment: Yep, that's correct about your `grid8x8` deduction. Though I would personally be more specific about that array part, saying that `grid8x8` is a reference to an array of 8 arrays of 8 pointers to `SomeClass`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `typedef` means:  `grid8x8` is a reference to an 8x8 array of pointers to `SomeClass`.

The `SomeOtherClass::getGrid` function is, I'd imagine, returning a reference then to a member variable `SomeOtherClass::grid`.

I would do it this way instead:

```
typedef SomeClass* (grid8x8)[8][8];


const grid8x8& SomeOtherClass::getGrid()
{
    return grid;
}
```

That way, you can have a `grid8x8` OR a reference to a `grid8x8`.  A little more versatile, and you're less likely to forget you're using that reference at times when you shouldn't.`

Comment: James Root, nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a C++11 answer (question is tagged C++ after all)

You could use a `std::array` to store your grids instead of C arrays. Depending on your preference towards templates the syntax is somewhat straightforward.

```
#include <array>
typedef std::array<std::array<SomeClass*, 8>, 8> grid8x8;
```

Comment: I thought of refactoring the code later to suit C++11, so I consider this to be very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is a reference (`(&)`) to a 8 by 8 array (`[8][8]`) of pointers (`*`) to integers (`int`). Start parsing inside the innermost parenthesis right to left, then to the right and finally to the left again. In contrast, a reference to a pointer to an 8 by 8 array of ints would look like this:

```
typedef int (*& RefToPtrToGrid)[2][2];
```

Personally, I find c++11 style more readable:

```
using RefTo8x8GridofPtr = int* (&) [8][8];

//or even better with std::array 
using Grid8x8 = std::array<std::array<int*,8>,8>&;

//or, more flexible:
template<size_t M,size_t N>
using Grid = std::array<std::array<int*,N>,M>&; //usage: Grid<8,8> myGrid;
```

Also, as @Will Briggs said, you probably don't want to make the reference part of the type:

```
using Grid8x8 = int* [8][8];
//... and so on
```